# How to add and display inner html and document.getelementby id values

Tags: javascript, html, css

Have spent quite some time attempting this and cannot find a way to work it can anyone help? I am trying to add the slider value to the toggle switch value and give an output upon button press or page load

Codes here

```js
// Slider Code
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

//Toggle Switch Code

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      // do this
      console.log('Checked');
      var toggleoutput = 2000
    } else {
      // do that
      console.log('Not checked');
      var toggleoutput = 0
    }
  });
});
//Grab Sum Script
function getSum() {

  var toggleoutputfinal = document.getElementById("toggleoutput").value;
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = this.value + toggleoutputfinal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/switch.css" />
  <div>
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider-pic" id="myRange">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  </div>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

  <br>

  <button onclick="document.innerHTML(toggleoutput + demo)">Click me</button>
  <span id="sum"></span>

  <script src="js/demo.js"></script>

</body>
```

The toggle switch and slider code functions work properly but the added value does not appear after button press so i assume the getsum function doesn't work but i am not confident in js to fix it

Comment: It would probably be easier if you just checked the checkbox inside of your `getSum` method. Is there a reason why you were separating them?

Comment: The script im attempting to build is a calculator type thing with certain toggles having different values and sliders also having different values so the user selects what toggles they want enabled and it calculates a final value so i didnt think merging them would be a great idea

Comment: Got it. You should look into how variable scope works in javascript to get a better understanding. Basically, you would want to declare `toggleOutput` outside of the event listeners and other methods. Right now, it only exists in the scope of your checkbox event handler. Also, inside of `getSum` I see `document.getElementById("toggleoutput")` but you don't seem to have any html elements with that id.

Comment: Yeah i got that just now but it only displays the toggle value, not the total value

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it solution is here
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/switch.css"/>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider-pic" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<br>

<button onclick="getSum()">Click me</button>
<span id="sum"></span>

<script src="js/demo.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS

```
var toggleoutput = 0

// Slider Code
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

//Toggle Switch Code

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
    
      checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (checkbox.checked) {
          // do this
          console.log('Checked');
          toggleoutput = 2000
        } else {
          // do that
          console.log('Not checked');
          toggleoutput = 0
        }
      });
    });
 //Grab Sum Script
        function getSum() {
        document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = +slider.value + +toggleoutput;
}
```